# Cadence can't start ALSA -> PulseAudio -> Jack (Plugin) bridge

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

[image]
[image]

In both images you see that the "start" button is disabled. How does one fix this bridge?

The PulseAudio bridge displays the start button, but when clicked nothing happens.

[image]

```
karl@karl-ux303ln:~$ ps aux | grep pulseaudio
karl      1832  0.0  0.0 757252 10128 ?        S<l  16:22   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
karl      3985  0.0  0.0  34472  2368 pts/2    S+   16:34   0:00 grep --color=auto pulseaudio

karl@karl-ux303ln:~$ ps aux | grep jackd
karl      3820  1.2  0.7 221820 93600 ?        SLsl 16:32   0:00 /usr/bin/jackdbus auto
karl      3961  0.0  0.0  34468  2360 pts/2    S+   16:33   0:00 grep --color=auto jackd
```

I it that my system already routes alsa to pulseaudio? And that I only need to route from pulseaudio to jack?

Answer (score 0):

You have alsa routed to pulseaudio and then to jack. It's always on so you don't need to start it.
If you don't want to use pulseaudio, click the dropdown box labeled "bridge type" and select ALSA -> JACK if available.